# How can I remove paddins from my styled text in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to remove the padding at the bottom and top of the text, but I haven't been able to remove the padding successfully, any suggestions?

```
Text(
    text = "DT",
    color = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Black,
    style = androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle(
        fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    ),
    fontSize = 54.sp,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp),
)
```

[image: padding error]

Comment: Take a look into this compose issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171394808. I think it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PlatformTextStyle attribute to set   `includeFontPadding = false`

Example:

```
Text(
      text = text,
      style = TextStyle(
          platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
              includeFontPadding = false
          )
      )
  )
```

Details:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/05/whats-new-in-jetpack-compose.html

Comment: As you can see above, the style is already being set.  Is there no other option?

Comment: Have you set `includeFontPadding = false`?